MiniApps на Nest.js
Хотел узнать несколько вопросов, касательно telegram-bot-api.
На Nest.js делаю backend и пробую фронт фигачить.
Настроил ответы на сообщения и возник вопрос. Как мне получить аву пользователя, для её отрисовки в mini-app? name, username, id и т.д. всё это есть, а откуда аву достать и вообще, можно ли её достать, я не понимаю...
И ещё вопросик, касательно шрифтов. Поддерживает ли Telegram Mini-app шрифты из css font-family? Хочу сделать шрифты "Courier new", либо "Monospace", но, вроде, где-то читал, что телега не все шрифты может отрисовать, это так?

По-моему следует разделить вопросы.  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
